# can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?) - iptables is not present

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nginx, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install NGINX and Certificate by following this article in WSL:
[How to Install and Configure Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04#:%7E:text=1%20How%20to%20Install%20and%20Configure%20Nginx%20on,...%207%20Test%20Nginx.%20...%208%20More%20items)

But at the **Step 5: Allow Nginx Traffic**, I am getting error after the command **sudo ufw allow 'nginx http'**.

The error we are facing is

```
WARN: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Skipping adding existing rule
```

While I listed the files in /etc/modprobe.d I didn't find iptable file

Can anyone help to resolve this.

Tried to install NGINX and SSL

Comment: Cross-posted on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1451093/1165986).  Recommend continuing and consolidating discussion there unless someone has a validated answer.  Thanks!